Crossing symmetry in electroweak theory
Suppose I want to evaluate the transition amplitude of $ZZ->W^+W^-$. I've already done all the calculations for the amplitude $W^+Z->W^+Z$ so I would simply be tempted to use crossing symmetry (which, to my understanding, also holds for singular Feynmann diagrams). However, for the latter amplitude, I have an S-channel diagram as well as U-channel diagram, with a W+ as virtual particle. I don't see how I could have the corresponding diagrams in the case $ZZ ->W^+W^-$ since no WWW vertex exists and neither $Z$ nor $\gamma$ could be used for the same reason.

What about a virtual Higgs boson?
